Is there a way to resize an image within a circle, without changing the size of the circle?
I'm trying to resize an image within a circle, but I can only change the size of the image and the circle together. I'm assuming this is because of border-radius, but I'm not sure else to do it.
I'm trying to turn this:

Into this:



.Nova {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  object-position: 0px 0px;
}
<img src="https://i.sstatic.net/xFBKyZNi.png" class="Nova" />




You maybe could learn a bit about aspect ratios because it sounds as though your image isn't filling the circle because it's not as tall as it's wide, though without more information we can't be certain.

@AHaworth The image completely fills the circle, it's a perfect square image. It's a portrait, but in the original image, the face is off center, so making it a circle cuts off the top right of the persons head. I guess I'm asking how to change the center of the image so the circle shows the full face of the person in the picture, instead of half of it.

You need to decide which part of the image (the part needs to be a square) is to be in the circle.

You can swap the actual img for a background and position and size that.
This snippet doubles the size and positions it at the top right. On this image that happens to be good enough to get the head and shoulders in.


.Nova {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url(https://i.sstatic.net/xFBKyZNi.png);
  background-size: 800px 800px;
  background-position: top right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
<img class="Nova" />




Something like this (but you either need a higher-resolution image, or use SVG so the quality does not drop when zoomed)


.img-wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  object-position: 0px 0px;
}

.Nova {
    position: relative;
    zoom: 2;
    right: 100%;
}
<div class="img-wrapper">
    <img src="https://i.sstatic.net/xFBKyZNi.png" class="Nova" />
</div>



